# Customizing a Sub Grid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to create a custom Table(using HTML page) as above with fixed header and data in rows with sliders(similar to crm design).Does anyone have any idea or relevant information on doing this.Please guide me.

Comment: Is this table for use in CRM, or just meant to look like it? Where is it being used (embedded in a CRM form, in an external application etc)?

Comment: The answer depends of which version of CRM you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CRM 2011 there is another option that is using Silverlight as Web Resource. Take a look in this samples:

- In SDK in folder `samplecode/cs/Silverlight/restsilverlightcontacteditor`
- http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2013/01/crm-2011-lookup-functionality-in.html